# Header "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" not coming in response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

My application makes a lot of calls to the graph API to get the properties I need. It is impossible to reduce the number of requests in my case. And for this, I need to understand when the number of requests approaches the limit and that I need to stop doing them so as not to get 429)

The documentation says that the parameter "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" should come in the header when the number of requests approaches the limit from 0.8. As I understand it, 0.8 is a coefficient from 1, where 1 is the upper limit of the limit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?view=graph-rest-1.0#regular-responses-requests

But I didn’t get this parameter in the header, although Retry-After with TooManyRequests.

How can I get this parameter in the response? Perhaps you need to specify additional parameters for this? Or set up Tenant for this?

Or is there another way to view throttle-limit?

Thanks in advance for your reply)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" parameter in header response, this means that you haven't consumed more than 0.8 of its limit, its mentioned in docs. please check the screenshot.
[image]

You can check service specific throttle limit ,please follow [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?view=graph-rest-1.0#service-specific-limits) ,

We were curious to know, what service you were hitting ?

Comment: But I get a response of 429 which means that the number of requests has already been exceeded
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?view=graph-rest-1.0#sample-response
But in none of the cases I get "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage"

Comment: Right! The best thing for you to do is to check the Retry-After header then resubmit the requests after that interval , As well as adding a check for the "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" which might not be available in the throttled response As motioned in above image , it will only available if you consumed 0.8 of its limit but throttling is due to large no of request - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling?view=graph-rest-1.0#best-practices-to-handle-throttling

Comment: If you are ok with it ,could you please help us with what services you were using .

Comment: I am using GraphServiceClient by example. But with a small fix, I also add my own ResponseHandler to keep track of requests and responses that pass through the GraphServiceClient

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS
@vicky kumar

Comment: But shouldn't the response with "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" in the header arrive before the "Retry-After" response is triggered?

Comment: Hi @DimaBond
Could you please provide the URI which you were using In graph explorer and the also share the request Id which failed with 429 error for your further investigation .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow... In which scenarios will I get the "Retry-After" header but not the "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" header?

I'm using Azure AD, and at some point, I'm getting a 429 error in the response
return code, however in none of the responses I saw the "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" header. How can that be?

To simplify things, let's say I have a rate limit of 100 requests per second. After 80 requests, I should start getting the "x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage" value in the headers of the response, isn't it?